# What AMD processors provide RDRAND?

Tags: cpu, random-number-generator

The latest AMD programmer manuals, dated June 2015, include the `RDRAND` instruction in the instruction set. Confer, [AMD64 Architecture Programmer’s Manual Volume 3: General-Purpose and System Instructions](http://support.amd.com/TechDocs/24594.pdf), page 279. The description of the instruction is:

> Loads the destination register with a hardware-generated random value.

I can't find information on AMD's site about RDRAND-enabled processors. Confer, [rdrand site:amd.com](http://www.google.com/search?q=rdrand+site%3Aamd.com). Additionally, AMD is ***not*** listed at Wikipedia's [Comparison of hardware random number generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hardware_random_number_generators) (or other similar pages).

What AMD processors support RDRAND?

---

A related question is open at the [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). The Crypto.SE question is interested in the security properties and security evaluations for the circuit. See [AMD and RDRAND instruction](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/29894).

Comment: [Excavator Architecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excavator_(microarchitecture))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only AMD architecture that supports RDRAND at this point is their Excavator core. It is used in a few mobile APUs, specifically the 8000-series ones (like [FX-8800P](http://products.amd.com/en-us/search/APU/AMD-FX-Series-Processors/AMD-FX-Series-Processors-for-Laptops/FX-8800P-with-Radeon%E2%84%A2-R7-Graphics/123)). The first desktop product with it is [Athlon X4 845](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-Athlon%20X4%20845.html).

Unfortunately, I have not been able to find any AMD resource confirming this. However, [this site](http://www.cpu-world.com/cgi-bin/CPUID.pl?CPUID=51012) lists the CPUID information of at least one such APU model, showing RDRAND support.

AMD's next generation of CPUs, starting with Ryzen will [reportedly](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-Zen-CPU-Znver1) also include support for RDSEED.

Comment: @jww good to know